# Dropzone acceptedFiles filter fails in android chrome devices while uploading music files

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, google-chrome, dropzone

Dropzone always prompt error `You can't upload files of this type` in mobile devices (chrome browser). As I deeply checked the code I fount that the HTML `file` object property `type` is empty also `file.name` doesn't show the file extension this happens only when I upload music files in android chrome browser. How can I overcome this issue?